# UIAccelerometer Detecting angle Problem

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

How to detect the iPhone angle?
I mean that when iPhone is straight (i.e) HomeButton is in bottom part, so how to detect 90 Degree from UIAccelerometer Method.

```
CGFloat RadiansToDegrees(CGFloat radians) {return radians * 180/M_PI;};
```

i try RadiansToDegrees(atan2(acceleration.y, acceleration.x)) but it gives -90 degree angle

any helpwould be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just an issue of sign, use

```
return - RadiansToDegrees(atan2(acceleration.y, acceleration.x));
```